# What difference should I expect when running a unit test vs debugging a unit test in VS?

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, mstest

## Background

I have a ViewModel that I want to unit test using the built-in test framework from Visual Studio.

```
public async Task RefreshEntries(string rootID)
{
    _isCurrentlyFetchingEntries = true; 
    if (_entriesCollectionSource == null)
        _entriesCollectionSource = new ObservableCollection<ExplorerDisplayEntryDTO>();
    _entriesCollectionSource.Clear();
    Entries = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_entriesCollectionSource);
    var entries = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var toReturn = (...) // Fetch plenty of things in my repo
        return toReturn;
    });

    foreach (var entry in entries)
    {
        _entriesCollectionSource.Add(entry);
    }   
    Entries.Filter = _customizedFilter;
    _isCurrentlyFetchingEntries = false;
}
```

I wrote a unit test that will indirectly `await` this specific task (through multiple calls all around the ViewModel).

When **running** the unit test, (CTRL+R, T) it passes with no issue.

When **debugging** the unit test, an exception is thrown at line 16 of the snippet above

When **running** the **program** normally (both in debug and release mode), the method does not trigger any error.

> **System.NotSupportedException** This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread

I took a look at the parallel stacks window and it seems that when running normally (and I suspect, when running the unit test), the line is executed by the main thread. Whereas it seems to be executed by some other thread while debugging the test.

## Question

What sort of behavior changes should I expect when **running** a unit test vs **debugging** a unit test?

Comment: Are you running your test in an STAThread? Are you using a WPF application object? Try putting the GetDefaultView line just before the Filter line. My guess is that the bug is there when running outside the debugger as well; it's just not reported. I added a WPF tag.

Comment: If you had a `ConfigureAwait(false)` on your Task.Run it would have this problem.

Comment: Okay, I didn't notice the exception was swallowed when running the test instead of debugging it. So it's probably throwing during the test run (as you said), but raised explicitly during the test debugging. I tried adding a `[STAThread]` annotation to the test, and adding `ConfigureAwait(false)` but the exception is still thrown when debugging.

Comment: Actually, adding `ConfigureAwait(false)` would likely *provoke* the problem if it didn't exist (for more info, [read this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq)). Is the exception thrown if you remove it, and keep `[STAThread]` ?

Comment: Can you show the code for the test?

Comment: When narrowing down my test code to find out which exact instruction leads to the code above, I found out that I registered an `async void`  method to the `PropertyChanged` of `INotifyPropertyChanged`. This method would then call the code shown above. I'll dig into that because I suspect this could be causing at least part of the issue. Will update the question / post an answer if what I suspect is true.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as it may sound, the main difference between unit testing and debugging unit testing in VS is: to find the exact root cause at the code level to fix the errors and bugs found during the testing

Comment: Why does it change the behavior of my code ?

Comment: @ArthurAttout, you said your code runs perfectly no errors when running the program normally. while you get a System.NotSupportedException error when you debug it. the functionality of your code did not change a single bit, all the story is that VS is trying to tell you if you want to run your program in debugging mode, you need to fix this System.NotSupportedExpection error you have.  try reading Microsoft's Docs about this error in this link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.notsupportedexception?view=net-5.0

Comment: If an exception is thrown in the snippet above, and given the fact that I never use `Task.Run` without `await`, shouldn't the exception be escalated even when running the test ? Unless I'm mistaken, if a VS test encounters an unhandled exception, the test should fail. Hence, if no unhandled exception shows up in running mode BUT an unhandled exception happens in debug mode, I can only conclude the behavior of the code is changing.

Comment: @ArthurAttout, allow me to shed light on the fact that program and code behaviour (functionality) does not change on its own, if you told your code/program to await it will, if you told it to start it will, the same thing with all commands, that's why it is called instruction. now regarding your code, and regarding the part of you using the await try using Async